# BuildConfig has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies. Android

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project that uses gradle with library project as dependency.Dependency project has same package name as project.When I try to build the project but failed.

Here is the folder structure with files in question:

Library AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test"
    android:allowBackup="true">


</manifest>
```

Library build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    enforceUniquePackageName false
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    enforceUniquePackageName false
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':testLib')
}
```

Error Message :

```
Error:Class com.test.BuildConfig has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
1 error; aborting

  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/test/BuildConfig;
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
        at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    1 error; aborting
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one way - rename one of packages. I tried to add 'exclude' option to build.gradle, but it was not successful attempt. Meantime, it was not option, because of your app needs both BuildConfig classes.